# Complete Excel sheet with data from CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-2019

I have this .xls file:

```
| ID |  SKU   | Description | etc
---------------------------------
|    | prod_A | Lorem ip... | etc
---------------------------------
|    | prod_B | Lorem ip... | etc
---------------------------------
|    | prod_C | Lorem ip... | etc
---------------------------------
```

and I have this CSV:

```
|  SKU   | ID |
---------------
| prod_A |  1 |
---------------
| prod_B |  2 |
---------------
| prod_C |  3 |
---------------
```

Can I automatically import the ID of each SKU into the Excel file?

Other info:
SKUs do not follow the same order in the two rows. Not all SKUs in one file are also present in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the formula below in cell A2 of your xls file:

```
=INDEX(test.csv!$B:$B,MATCH($B$2:$B5,test.csv!$A:$A,0))
```

It looks up for the SKU in the csv file (in my case `test.csv`), and returns its ID found in `test.csv`. When the SKU value does not exist, `#N/A` is returned. In my test data, the SKU value `d` exists in the xls file but not in the csv file. See images below for the data and returned results.

If your version has XLOOKUP function, then you can use this formula instead of the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions:

```
=XLOOKUP($B$2:$B$5,test.csv!$A:$A,test.csv!$B:$B)
```

**Test.csv**

[image]

**Xls file**
[image]

**Edit:**
If you don't want to see "#N/A", and prefers an empty cell, then englobe the formula inside an `IFNA` function. The formula becomes:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(test.csv!$B:$B,MATCH($B$2:$B5,test.csv!$A:$A,0)),"")
```

Depending on the PC's regional settings, commas should be changed to semi-colons.

Comment: For me, on Excel 2019, it only worked by changing the commas with semicolons: `=INDEX(test.csv!$B:$B;MATCH($B$2:$B5;test.csv!$A:$A;0))`

Comment: Is possible to have an empty cell instead with #N/A?

Comment: @Felix Yes, it is possible. See edit. See also why you needed semi-colons. If the answer solves your question, you can mark it as accepted. Visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how the site works.